# Is it possible to build a CI pipeline where the dev and test Automation code are maintained separately as two different project on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, katalon-studio, testautomationfx

I am currently using azure DevOps for the current project where the entire code of the application is maintained as a project and the test Automation code is maintained as another separate project.  Now I want to do build a CI pipeline thru azure pipeline and integrate my Automation code.

My question is: will it be possible to perform a CI by building a pipeline where the developers' code and the Automation code is maintained in two different projects.

FYI: I am currently using Katalon Studio for developing my Automation scripts.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git, you can follow the instructions on MSDN, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).

you just need to configure the build/automation steps according to the checkout path.

In case you are using TFVC, i am not sure. But in this case you could use the binary output from the Dev Code as an Artifact input for the automation project, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YAML pipeline, you can check out multiple repositories in your pipeline by syntax `checkout` .

Declaring the repository using inline syntax:

```
steps:
- checkout: self  # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

This example has two checkout steps, which check out the repo declared as repository resource along with the current self repository that contains the pipeline YAML.

If you are using the classic pipeline, as workaround, in the beginning of the build you can add a Command Line task or a PowerShell task that clone the second repo into `s` folder on the agent.

[image]